# How do I load into an array all the elements in one variable of an enum?

Tags: java, arrays, enums

I'm trying to get the elements of one enum variable into an array using a method in another class (I hope I'm explaining that right, please look at the code)

I've tried all kinds of things, for loops, with and without constructors.

```
public enum coffeetypes {
    COFFEE1 ("AMERICANO", "LATTE", "CAPPUCCINO"),
    COFFEE2 ("ESPRESSO", "RISTRETTO", "AMERICANO"), ;   
}
```

I want to get the result

```
"AMERICANO", "LATTE", "CAPPUCCINO" 
or "ESPRESSO", "RISTRETTO", "AMERICANO"
not "AMERICANO" "ESPRESSO"
```

Comment: Yeah I tried it with a constructor but couldn't figure out how to do anything except make three separate functions each returning one of the elements. Which also meant that there needed to be the same number of elements for each or there would be some error.

Thanks for the responses, looks like they should work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your enum type doesn't even compile as it is missing a constructor and a private field.
When adding this, it is easy to add a getElements() method so you can access the list from outside your enum:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Coffee {

    public enum CoffeeTypes {
        COFFEE1("AMERICANO", "LATTE", "CAPPUCCINO"), 
        COFFEE2("ESPRESSO", "RISTRETTO", "AMERICANO");
        String[] elements;
        private CoffeeTypes(String... elements)
        {
            this.elements=elements;
        }
        public String[] getElements()
        {
            return elements;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CoffeeTypes myinstance=CoffeeTypes.COFFEE1;
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(myinstance.getElements()));
    }

}
```

Arrays.asList is just used to print the array in a readable way.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a field for each property.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class Coffee {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(CoffeeTypes.COFFEE1.getAttributes());
    }

    public enum CoffeeTypes {
        COFFEE1 ("AMERICANO", "LATTE", "CAPPUCCINO"),
        COFFEE2 ("ESPRESSO", "RISTRETTO", "AMERICANO");

        private String n1;
        private String n2;
        private String n3;

        CoffeeTypes(String n1, String n2, String n3) {
            this.n1 = n1;
            this.n2 = n2;
            this.n3 = n3;
        }

        public List<String> getAttributes() {
            return Arrays.asList(n1, n2, n3);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[AMERICANO, LATTE, CAPPUCCINO]
```

Comment: @c0der you are right. I renamed the class and forgot to also rename the constructor.